# Can I change label text in AngularJs Directly from view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in my `HTML`

```
<span ng-class="newProvider ? 'newProvider' : ''" 
      class="help-block">
          {{ 'new-product.provider.helper' | locate }}
</span>
```

When newProvider is true, I need to load another text like

```
{{ 'new-product.provider.newProvider' | locate }}
```

Is there anyway I can do this check for the label content?
And if not, how should I load this text in the controller?

Comment: When newProvider is false, you dont want to show the span? If so then use `ng-if="newProvider"`

Comment: I show always, when is `true`, must be in a color and say something, and when `false` other color and other text.. I guess I could hide one and show another label.. But is there a way to do in the same label?

Comment: I prefer to change the text of the label

Comment: new-product.provider.helper is "Please type and filter through your providers"
And the other text should be, "This provider will be added"

Comment: Yes, the filter loads the text in english or spanish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a watcher over newProvider and modify the text in the attached function.

Use `$watch` for this. Here is a plunker for you to see: http://plnkr.co/edit/BAtiGXaCDIqQdw86KJwE?p=preview

However, I would prefer using `ng-show`, `ng-switch` or `ng-if`

Comment: Great, I used ng-if, I let my code here, if someone else needs it:

`<span ng-if="newProvider" class="help-block newProvider">
    {{ 'new-product.provider.newHelper' | locate }}
</span>
<span ng-if="!newProvider" class="help-block">
    {{ 'new-product.provider.helper' | locate }}
</span>`